# NoClassDefFound - two lines after first use of the Class

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I use a .dll to in my Java project (Eclipse IDE if it helps), 
say this .dll contains Class "myclass" and I imported it. No Errors while building.

I'm having a problem (NoClassDefFound) with the following code:

```
byte[] sources = myclass.getsources();

myclass.close();
```

in the second line I get a NoClassDefFoundError, but not in the first one!
Both lines occur in the same method, with just 3-4 lines between them (these lines are guaranteed to be unrelated to myclass).

How can this be? How can `.getsources` work some lines above if there is NoClassDefFound?
I hope I have provided enough information, can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace, and the Java source code of the two methods, and the declaration of `myclass`.

Comment: I cannot provide sourcecode of the 2 Methods, because I do not have it. (may not be called .dll, its a bought piece of work, it contains classes, I may not see source) sorry, but you know what i know...
May there be a ClassDef of a class missing that is used inside .close()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may miss the class of "myclass " object. or that class is not inyour class path. Definitly classloader cannot load the class from your path. Check the classpath of that particular class.

Comment: all methods are static methods of myclass.
I would be happy if it would just not find the class, but in that case myclass.getsources() wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: do one thing print the size of byte array and comment myclass.close(). lets see what happen. you may get the same error i think so.

Comment: You were right, thank you! I'll try to work out the rest. But i would be gratefull if you could explain why .getsources() does not throw an exception?

Comment: you didnt used that object just declared and intialized. so  while running the program it will not be referenced because it didnt perform any action.

Comment: myclass.getsources() is nto an action, but myclass.close() is? sorry but i really don't get it^^

Comment: `byte[] sources = myclass.getsources();`   in this your source is  not perform any action means you are not using the source object any where so that  JVM never look for the method ' myclass.getsources();`      but in the case of `myclass.close()` JVM Definitly check. [ if you print th byte(source) at that time Jvm check for that method because the object is used at that time].

Comment: i will give you a good example  `String str=null;` you can define that but if you trying to print str you will get null pointer exception. bcoz jvm refer that obj  when you use that object

Comment: ok i think get it, if i dont use the bytes, the JVM does not care for where to get them from. Thank you for your patience :)